# Firestore security rules for Chat collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an app where two users can send messages to each other. My `Chat` collection structure is as follows:

```
Chat 
  -lastSentMessage: text
  -dateOfLastMessage: date 
  -users: [id1, id2] - array of users who are in the Chat
  * Messages - a collection of actual messages
```

Every document inside my `Chat` collection is either `id1_id2` or `id2_id1`. When I wrote my firestore rules, I initally wrote them like:

```js
match /Chats/{chatId} {
  function isUserInChat(){
    return request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Chats/$(chatId)).data.users;
  }

  allow create: if isUserAuthenticated();
  allow read: if isUserAuthenticated() && isUserInChat();
  allow update: if isUserAuthenticated() && isUserInChat();
  match /Messages/{messageId}{
     allow create: if isUserAuthenticated() && isUserInChat();
     allow read: if isUserAuthenticated() && isUserInChat();
     allow update: if isUserAuthenticated() && isUserInChat();
  }
}
```

And to me, this does make sense - user can read, update, and create chats and messages only if this user participates in the chat.

The problem I have with the above rules is when the user loads the app I call a listener to listen to the `Chats` collection and bring me all the chats in which this user participates. However, I have a firestore error `permissions denied` or something similar and this makes sense. I am trying to go through all `Chats` documents and read them all, even though, I am not part of all of them. So I changed the above rules to something like:

```js
match /Chats/{chatId} {
  function isUserInChat(){
    return request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Chats/$(chatId)).data.users;
  }

  allow create: if isUserAuthenticated();
  allow read: if isUserAuthenticated(); //this change causes me concern
  allow update: if isUserAuthenticated() && isUserInChat();
  match /Messages/{messageId}{
     allow create: if isUserAuthenticated() && isUserInChat();
     allow read: if isUserAuthenticated() && isUserInChat();
     allow update: if isUserAuthenticated() && isUserInChat();
  }
}
```

So now, I don't have the firestore error `permission denied`, however, I am exposing too much data which is not OK. Everyone can read everyone's `lastMessage` and when it was sent.

How do I fix this situation? Is there anything I can do, or which approach is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're explicitly loading the current document, which isn't necessary - but also leads to the rules engine being unable to guarantee that your read operation matches the rules you've set.

As far as I can tell, your `isUserInChat` should be:

```
function isUserInChat(){
  return request.auth.uid in resource.data.users;
}
```

So instead of calling `get` to load the document, just use the *current* document.

In your code that reads the documents and isn't working (which you forgot to share in your question), make sure that you include the same condition: so only tell it to read documents where the current UID is in the `users` array field. Without that it won't work, as [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters).